# Box2D: can i transfer fixtures to other bodies?

Tags: java, c#, box2d, fixture

I've been playing around with libgdx and box2d for a couple of days, my question is:

Can i make a body split into multiple bodies, and split the fixtures between the two bodies?

[image: visual]

1. starting body consisting of 15 fixtures
2. 4 fixtures get destroyed
3. starting body create a second body, transferring some fixtures to it
4. the 2 bodies act independently

i can use a fill flood to check if a bodys fixtures does not connect anymore, so what i need  help with is tips, or code that can help me split the body in multiple other bodies and distribute the fixtures without creating new ones

if that makes sense..

Comment: No, Box2D does not have any handy feature to help you with this. You basically need to create a new body the way you would create a body normally.

Answer (score 0):

While Box2D doesn't directly support transferring of fixtures to other bodies as iforce2d has explained, you can achieve something like the overall effect you've described by using multiple bodies to begin with and binding them together into the large cluster using joints like weld joints. Then when destroying bodies, the joints holding them together also go away eventually leaving multiple cluster fragments that act independently.

I'd put together a demo of this in [PlayRho](https://github.com/louis-langholtz/PlayRho) (a physics engine that I've been developing that's based off of Box2D). Here's what it looks like:

[image]

While this is a different physics engine, the same concepts apply just fine to Box2D. Hope this helps.